# Can I contribute to my IRA from 2018 still?

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, roth-ira

I put in my tax filing for 2018 that I had contributed $5500 to a Roth IRA, but due to technical difficulties with my investment account I didn't get around to funding it until now, but it looks like I'm not allowed to contribute for 2018 anymore. Is there any way to get around it since I already filed taxes saying I did so? Or do I need to file an amended return saying I didn't contribute to that IRA?

Comment: _Where_ on your tax return did you tell the IRS that you contributed to a Roth IRA? IIRC, Roth contributions are not listed anywhere on the income tax forms.

Comment: I think I must have messed up, because they're listed in a deductible.

Comment: @DilipSarwate. While a Roth doesn't appear on the 1040 it is asked about by TurboTax. It is easy to think that every question you answer in the tax software ends up someplace on an IRS or state income tax form.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I agree that it is easy to think that every question asked by tax software ends uo somewhere on a tax form that the IRS or State revenue service gets, in _this_ instance, the OP has stated, in a comment above, that he actually entered the _Roth_ contribution, that he never actually made, as a _deductible_ Traditional IRA contribution. Whatever the OP (or anyone else) might believe about tax software, the OP committed two acts of commission, _not_ omission, by (1) _failing_ to make a IRA contribution of any kind, and (2) falsely claiming that he made a _deductible_ contribution,

Comment: @mhoran_psprep (continued) and that's what he needs to fix ASAP.  (1) cannot be fixed in that the deadline for making a IRA contribution is past, but (2) needs to be fixed by filing a amended return rather than wait for the IRS computers to catch up with reconciling its information from the IRA custodians with the OP's tax return.

Answer (score 5):

According to IRS:

> What is the deadline to make contributions?
>
> Your tax return filing deadline (not including extensions). For example, you can make 2018 IRA contributions until April 15, 2019.

https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/traditional-and-roth-iras

Furthermore,

> Contributions to a Roth IRA aren't deductible (**and you don't report the contributions on your tax return**), but qualified distributions or distributions that are a return of contributions aren't subject to tax.

https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc451

Therefore, contributing or not contributing to Roth IRA does not affect your tax return, and thus does not require filing an amended one - but, since you're saying that you've reflected your contribution somewhere in your tax return, whereas it needed not be there, you may need to correct *that* part.

Comment: OP also asking about income limits for a 2019 Ruth deposit. Care to add that?

Comment: +1 to void_ptr.  @JoeTaxpayer Actually, the OP asked _only_ about a MAGI calculator and didn't _specifically_ ask about income limits for contributing to a Roth IRA.

Comment: Well, service/product recommendation are off topic. :P  even the IRS changes their web site and links break.

Answer (score 2):

When you write $5500 on Line 32 of the new Schedule 1 of the new Form 1040, the IRS assumes that it is a (deductible) contribution to a Traditional IRA. In May, all the custodians of your various IRA accounts will send Form 5438 to the IRS (with a copy to you) telling the IRS what contributions you made your IRA account (as well as what distributions you took, etc) and a few months after that when the IRS computers have had time to match up all the information IRS has received, the IRS will know about the discrepancy; that you have claimed a $5500 deduction for contributing to a Traditional IRA but you haven't actually made the contribution. As the answer by void_ptr points out, there is no way for you to fix the problem by making the 2018 contribution now; the contribution deadline was last Monday.

*You owe more tax than is shown on your 2018 Form 1040* that you sent to the IRS, and if you got a refund from the IRS already, you should have received a smaller refund.  What you need to do right away is file Form 1040X to *amend* your 2018 return to remove the claim about having made a tax-deductible $5500 contribution to your Traditional IRA, recompute the tax that is due from you, and send the IRS a check for what you owe them. Don't wait for the IRS to discover the discrepancy and bill you for the difference; if you do, you will owe not just the additional income tax, but interest and possibly penalties as well.